# Как заставить программу максимально использовать ресурс процессора?

Tags: c

Есть программа, в которой по несколько раз подряд сортируются большие трёхмерные массивы. Сортировка занимает достаточно много времени. При этом, во время сортировки процессор нагружается от силы на 40%. Задача - ускорить процесс за счёт более интенсивного использования процессора

Comment: 40% на ядро или процессор? сколько у вашего процессора ядер?

Comment: Программа работает в один поток, так что скорее всего ядро.

Comment: Не уверен, но вот кажется мне, что здесь узкое место - обращение к памяти, и как процессор не используй - это толку не даст. Не из-за него проблемы.

Comment: Зачем гадать, используйте profiler

Comment: Откуда число 40%? Покажите подробно, как именно оно получено.

Comment: Запускаете профилятор и смотрите, где больше всего тратится времени в Вашем алгоритме. Потом оптимизируете это место.

Comment: Правильный ответ для увеличения быстродействия и производительности это **OpenMP** https://www.openmp.org , https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

Comment: Алгоритм сортировки трогать нельзя

Comment: При чем тут алгоритм сортировки и скорость сортировки? Одно круглое, другое зелёное.. не трогайте алгоритм, распределите сортировку по нескольким потокам, именно это и делает OpenMP.

Comment: Может у вас просто не хватает RAM и во время сортировок начинается paging?

Comment: Памяти чуть меньше восьми гигов доступно

Answer (score 0):

Ну возможно включить высокий приоритет на приложение, найти "Узкое горлышко приложения" и сделать более продуктивным. Например чтоб ускорить приложение надо попробовать: задействовать SSE конструкции, использовать более быстрые алгоритмы, оптимизировать обращения к памяти

Comment: SSE использовать это самоубийство, из за версий simd и разного железа, в общем если есть желание чтобы софт не запускался в 50% случаев, то это самое оно :)

Comment: Ну если он делает для себя то можно)) А так я согласен что там пол софта не будет работать, а так остальные советы вроде норм